# Is it possible to use new and old SSL at the same?

Tags: tls

We are in the process of porting our servers from one cloud provider to another. Our SSL certificate is also about to expire. If I generate a new SSL certificate and put it on the new servers, will the about-to-expire certificate continue to work on the old servers? Yes, is my guess. Just wanted expert opinion.

Comment: Yes, a certificate is valid until its expiration time (assuming the chain is still valid and the certificate isn't revoked). The usual way to replace a certificate is to do so sometime before the previous one expires and rollout the new certificate progressively across servers. Merely generating a new certificate for the same domain does not invalidate the previous one.

Comment: Not also that you done have an old or new "SSL". SSL/TLS are the communication protocols, what you are talking about is the certificate used for authentication in these protocols. So the correct term to use is *certificate*.

Comment: Corrected, thank you for pointing that out.